# Can't start jasperserver. origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Tags: java, tomcat, jasperserver

I have installed Jasper server with bundled tomcat and pgsql by default values. When I start service tomcat started and pgsql too. But a few seconds later jasper tomcat stopped.
[image]
when i check my console 
 **catalina.out**

```
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.287 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.30
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Apr 3 2018 20:04:09 UTC
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.30.0
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.291 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.291 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-7.1.0/java
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.291 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_151-b12
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.291 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.291 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-7.1.0/apache-tomcat
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.291 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-7.1.0/apache-tomcat
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.291 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-7.1.0/apache-tomcat/conf/logging.properties
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.291 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.291 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms1024m
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.291 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx2048m
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.291 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xss2m
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.291 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djs.license.directory=/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-7.1.0
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.292 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.292 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.292 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.292 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.292 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-7.1.0/apache-tomcat
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.292 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-7.1.0/apache-tomcat
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.292 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-7.1.0/apache-tomcat/temp
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.292 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-7.1.0/common/lib:/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-7.1.0/postgresql/lib:/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-7.1.0/common/lib::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.567 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Jan-2020 14:26:18.574 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol-8080]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol-8080]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:655)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:995)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
```

Please help. How can i fix it?

Comment: i did re-installed jasper-server,change port and change protocol but it didn't work.

Comment: `Address already in use` shows you that a port is used by an other application. Find out which port and change it in your tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to start the server on a port which is already in use, try to change the server port, if you are using stand alone tomcat server, then do the following.

1. In your tomcat installation there will be a **conf** folder
2. Open server.xml file
3. Search for a line starting with **Connector port**
4. By default the port should be 8080, change it to some free port such as 8081
5. Restart tomcat server

if you are using spring's built in server then you can change the server port in the application.properties file as follows.

`server.port=9090` // any free port

Comment: i didn't see that he was using stand alone server, made the edit, thanks

Comment: You also do not see that op is using spring-boot. but it is tagged with tomcat so i guess OP is using a standalone version